# Read Array at index in jpa Query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a native Query that return a list of objects, i need to pass an array as parameter to the function `getAllUsers`.

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE code1=(?1)[0] AND code2=(?1)[1]")
    public List<Object[]> getAllUsers(List<String> list);
}
```

The problem was that i can't get values of the parameter `list` in the query : `code1=(?1)[0] AND code2=(?1)[1]`.

I tried to use Types :

`public List<Object[]> getAllUsers(String[] list);`

`public List<Object[]> getAllUsers(String ...list);`

But always without result

**Many thanks For any help**

Comment: the query you write is handled by the database, which has no clue what[0] and [1] mean, or what a java.util.Array is that is passed in as the single ?1 parameter. If you have multiple parameters to pass in to a query, you need to break them up as multiple parameters for your method as well ie: getAllUsersByCode1AndCode2(String code1, String code2) method.

Comment: does `code1` & `code2` are different columns in `users` table? if yes, then syntax is wrong & you might need to use 2 arguments in your method.

Comment: I used used `code1` and `code2` as example, in fact i have 24 : `code1, code2, code3, ... code24`, this is why it's not practical to use parameters ... also i can add codes (code25, 26, ...)

Comment: If you have different columns, then using list as method argument won't be correct. Also I am wondering if you really need to input 24 columns as `where` clause of your query.

Comment: @AshishPatil, i have a constraint to use those values as columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that `@Query` is the right way to do the dynamic query. You should consider the CriteriaAPI usage. You could try to use the `Specification` or `QueryDsl` https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl

Example of the solution your problem via Specification:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository 
    extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> { 

}

@Service
@RequiredAllArgConstuctor
public class UserService {
    
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public List<User> getAllUsers(List<String> codeArguments) {
        var specification = (Specification<T>) (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            var predicates = new Predicate[codeArguments.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < codeArguments.size(); i++) {
                var predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("code" + (i + 1)), codeArguments.get(i));
                predicates[i] = (predicate);
            }
            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates);
        };
       
        return userRepository.findAll(specification);
    }
}
```